# HTML5 canvas two canvas on top of another clear only top

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two canvas one top of another how i can clear only top canvas like a layer. 
Example if i use erase tool clear background, i need clear only drawings on top canvas.
`picture is` [Picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A5RI.jpg)
`demo is` [JsfidleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/avd62hxc/)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'foreground' canvas context is being created from your background canvas. Hence why its erasing the background. You should also attach your mouse up event to the html body; if you move off the canvas with the mousedown and mouse up outside the canvas its going to break your logic .